# Does British Airways website implements site prevention automation

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

While practicing Selenium, I tried to automate the British Airways site, where auto-suggestion dropdowns are used. When manually entering a few letters, the dropdowns display suggestions; when automating it, they don't, even if I use the wait method. I was told sites like this prevent automation as security measure, but is it so, please?

Here's my code:

```
driver.get("https://www.britishairways.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.id("from")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("from")).sendKeys("tor");
```

Comment: You can launch the Selenium-controlled and Chrome side-by-side and check the console for activity. It's possible that when you manually click and type in the box, it's selecting different control due to a script.

Comment: @Martheen, the control is the same. What's Selenium-controlled, though?

Comment: Unless you use headless option, there should be chrome window that's controlled by selenium, right?

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. But as I mentioned, it's all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any bot detection mechanism with in the British Airways website https://www.britishairways.com/.

To send a character sequence to the *From* field within the website, as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.britishairways.com/travel/home/public/en_in/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#from[name=\"searchEntry\"]"))).sendKeys("tor");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.britishairways.com/travel/home/public/en_in/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='from' and @name=\"searchEntry\"]"))).sendKeys("tor");
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: britishairways]

Comment: Thanks for showing me the method I'm not familiar with, but - as your screenshot demonstrates - it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use xpath or css selectors iso "id" when working on sites like that. Ids are usually less trusted attributes.